# Can't get value from input

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a guessing game with three questions and three guesses total but I can't get the value from the inputs so I can't progress any further. Rough draft for my code

```
guesses = 3
def guess():
  if guesses >= 0:
    alive = True
  else:
    print("You Failed")
Q1 = "What is 1+1"
Q2 = ""
Q3 = ""

def retry():
  input("Wrong Answer Try Again")
  
def questions():
  
 Q1 = input("What is 1+1")
    
def answer():
  if Q1 == "2":
    print("Q2")
  else:
    retry()
  if retry() == 2:
    print("Q2")

  
questions()
answer()
```

I've tried using lists functions if statements but I can't get the value of the inputs no matter what as its always a local variable.

Comment: Yes it is. You can declare it as global, which is a bad approach or return it from a function and pass that to another function.

Comment: The way you structure this depends on how the game is to be played. Looks like you will have three questions. Does the user have to get all three correct or do you want to keep track of how many correct answers have been given then report accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple approach to this problem.

The crucial part is the list of 2-tuples. Each tuple maintains a question and the correct answer to that question. By adding more questions and answers to the list your program can become more elaborate without having to change anything else in the code.

Something like this:

```
Questions = [("What is 1+1", "2"), ("What is 2+2", "4"), ("What is 3+3", "6")]

score = 0
TRIES = 3

for q, a in Questions:
    for _ in range(TRIES): # number of tries allowed
        if input(f'{q}? ').lower() == a.lower() :
            score += 1
            print('Correct')
            break
        else:   
            print("Incorrect please try again")
    else:
        print('Maximum tries exceeded')

print(f'Your final score is {score}')
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Finally was able to solve this problem albeit simple still was doing it for weeks with no progress haha.